# Inequality to prove Gradient is direction of steepest Ascent/descent

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given is : 
$f\left( y-t\frac { \triangledown f\left( y \right)  }{ \parallel \triangledown f(y)\parallel  }  \right) \le f(y+t*a)\le f(y+t\frac { \triangledown f(y) }{ \parallel \triangledown f(y)\parallel  } )$

t>0, (and t gets sufficiently small), a is an arbiatry vector with $\parallel a\parallel =1$

I want to prove that this inequality holds, and conclude with it that the Gradient points in the direction of steepest Ascent/Desenct.

From using the multidimensional intermediate value theorem on the RHS, you can conclude that:

$f(y+t\frac { \triangledown f(y) }{ \parallel \triangledown f(y)\parallel  } )-f(y+t*a)=\quad \triangledown f(\varepsilon )*(t\frac { \triangledown f(y) }{ \parallel \triangledown f(y)\parallel  } )$

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor expansion with Peano remainder, we have that
$$
f(y+ta) = f(y) + t\nabla f(y)^\top a + o(t).
$$

The objective is to minimize the RHS of the above inequality under the constraint that $\|a\|_2=1$. Because $t\to 0$, such minimization is equivalent to minimizing $\nabla f(y)^\top a$ because $f(y)$ does not depend on $a$. It is then obvious that the optimal solution is $a=\nabla f(y)/\|\nabla f(y)\|_2$.

Comment: is there another way  without using taylor expansion?

Comment: I think your approach with intermediate value theorem should also work. You only need to show $\|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(y+\epsilon a)\|_2\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, which is nothing but the assumption that $f$ is continuously differentiable